# How to rollback after use force push command

Tags: git

Question was so,I bring master branch and another merged.this operation is ok、going well.However,using `git push origin master` command,command line tell me"no fast forward".oh,so!then I from google find the answer was use "`git push -f`"....at last,On github my README file missing.

1、What should I do after use merge command.
2、Is there any way can be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

so you are using this command git push -f origin master.

if you want to change again, you can do commit and push again. It will be updated.

or if you want rollback, you can remove first with this command

git push origin :master

and push again.